# Web Crawler with multiprocessing in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing, web-crawler

I'm basically trying to get the same results as the code below, but using multiprocessing. The code below is a basic web crawler that prints all of the URLs within a given website. I want to be able to check for new urls from multiple sites at once using multiple processes. I have a separate web scraping script that uses pools and apply_async to scrape multiple sites at once, but I start with a static list of URLs. And then I have this script that iterates through one site at a time to get an entire list of non-duplicate URLs. I can't figure out how to get the best of both worlds though. Because my list of URLs is not static (it is being added to as new URLs are found), I don't know how to iterate through it and return results using apply_async.

I've read around, and I feel like queues may be a key to the solution, but I've tried everything and can't get it to work. Sorry for the crappy explanation. I'm still pretty new to python. Can someone help?

```
import lxml.html
import requests

url = "http://www.frontiercouriers.com"
url_check = "frontiercouriers.com"
urls = [url]
visited = [url]

while len (urls) >0:
    try:
        site_open = requests.get(urls[0])
        soup = lxml.html.fromstring(site_open.text)

        urls.pop(0)

        for href in soup.xpath('//a/@href'):
            if 'http' in href:
                site = href
            elif href.startswith('/'):
                site = str(url+href)
            else:
                site = str(url+'/'+href)

            if url_check in site and site not in visited:
                urls.append(site)
                visited.append(site)
                print (site)

    except Exception as e:
          print ("\n"+str(e))
          print (urls[0])
          urls.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) can perfectly match your needs, it calls urls in parallel, have a queue inside for accumulating requests and even have xpath capabilities built in, and the best part is that it is doing all this **without** multiprocessing by using twisted library async programming

Comment: Appreciate the response. But doesn't Scrapy only work with Python 2? I was hoping to figure out a solution in Python 3.

Comment: you are right, scrapy does not support python 3 yet, if python 2 is not an option for you I guess you'll have to implement a multiprocess solution yourself... not an easy task

Answer (score 1):

Even better would to use Asyncio Python3/ aiohttp. It is non-blocking, can fetch multiple urls at the same time without the need of spawning threads or use of twisted(scrapy) frameworks. [Check this link](https://github.com/omgbbqhaxx/python3.5-async-crawler/blob/master/async_crawler.py)